# Check multiple URL parameters with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

In my Spring controller I'm redirecting to a view and adding two parameters param1 and param2.
I want to make a div tag visible if param1 exists, so I check if param1 exists using Thymeleaf:

```
<div th:if="${param.keySet().contains('param1')}"> <p>something</p> </div>
```

And this will make the div visible...but if I add in the URL param2 too, it won't work anymore. Why? How do I make it work if I have multiple parameters? I want to use param2 for something else, take its value.

This is how my url looks like "/view?param1?param2=value".
Do I need to separate the params differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in URL character `?` means start getting params. You used twice `?`, so second only works, and `param1` it is not taken as a parameter.

If you want pass on multiple paramters in url, you should put character `&` between params. In your case the url will look like:

```
/view?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Comment: Other way to pass data in url is by path: